# BitmapFactory.decodeResource in unit-tests always return 32 pixels width and height

Tags: android, unit-testing, bitmap, pixel

I'm writing a unit test in which first I need to test the given resource's width and height and later use it with further assertions. However, no matter what pixels' drawable I pass to `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` it always returns `Bitmap` with width and height equals to **32 pixels**.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),
                  com.example.demo.test.R.drawable.big_icon);
assertNotNull("Bitmap is not null", bmp);
Log.d("Test", "Icon Height: " + bmp.getHeight());  // prints 32... why?
Log.d("Test", "Icon Width : ", bmp.getWidth());    // prints 32... why?
```

The resource (*big_icon*) I'm providing is placed under **drawable-nodpi** folder and is 512x512 pixels.

Why is this behavior occurring during unit-tests only? I can't find any reasonable explanation to this.

Comment: You better open an InputStream for the resourse and then use decodeFromStream.

Comment: @greenapps This is irrelative because I would want to inject a resource coming from **drawable** folder - not **raw** or **assets**.

Comment: Cant you open an InputStream from drawable then?

Comment: @greenapps can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well is it possible or not? I assumed you would have googled for it or tried already.

Comment: are you sure its the only `big_icon.png` under `res` folder?

Comment: @pskink yes there's only one png. No other variants included.

Comment: @greenapps Inputstream is useful when the resource is placed under raw or assets folder. That's why I asked you to elaborate since my setup is different.